# Twitter-like data authorization in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, authorization

I'm very new at Spring Boot, especially at Spring Security. I followed [this](https://bezkoder.com/spring-boot-jwt-auth-mongodb/) article and created an authentication and authorization flow. It makes some endpoints require authorization.Twitter does the same thing. It has some endpoints doesn't require authentication or authorization, but some does.

But with protected accounts, there is an another layer of authorization. For example; if I'm authenticated, I can fetch a protected account's follower list who I follow. BUT even if I'm authenticated I can't fetch a protected accounts' followers who I don't follow.

First thing come to my mind was that particular GET/POST method can search for their followers/followings, but that would be a terible solution. I've heard about Claim-Based Authorization. How can i give users authorities that are not static? Not like 'users:read' but '/*user_id*/:read'

Comment: You may want to have a look at Spring ACL, here's an article about Spring ACL https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-acl

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Excellent, I'll add that as an answer for the record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using Spring ACLs, aka Domain Object Security.

References :

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-acl
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/domain-acls.html